# Permission denied error attempting to add event to button in CodenameOne UI designer

Tags: codenameone

Permission denied error attempting to add event to button in CodenameOne UI designer ...

Cant add an event to a button I added via the codename one gui designer ... , a premission denied error comes up , cant run app myapp ...

Deleted project , tried again , same result..

Tried the Setup Netbeans option on GUI designer ... not sure what that is supposed to do .. but problem not resolved ...

Please help , would love to try this out and see it work :)

Netbeans 8.0 , Suse Linux 13.1 ...

Robi

Answer (score 0):

Click File->Setup NetBeans.

When the file chooser dialog pops up select the netbeans executable (the binary that runs netbeans). Previously instead of doing this you selected the java source file or something like that which we can't run hence the error.